# Are the Stack Overflow mugs dishwasher or microwave safe?

Tags: support, swag

I was recently sent a Stack Overflow mug. It's the nice big one with the code snippet about filling it with coffee on the back:

[image: a photo of the mug on my desk]

Is this mug dishwasher or microwave safe? I didn't receive any information about that with the swag drop. I'm assuming no for now.

Comment: Well, what's the criteria to get a mug? Or the team decides?

Comment: @Gourav This particular one was from [the 2018 Stuff-A-Way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321399/152515).

Comment: The implicit "banana for scale" pleases me.

Comment: Does putting too many of these in the dishwasher result in a **rack overflow**? Sorry I'll see myself out...

Comment: to know if they're microwave safe, try to heat coffee in it during 30 seconds. If the mug is hotter than the coffee, then it's not (and posts your findings as a self-answer)

Comment: You can run @Jean-Francois's experiment with water, too. Doesn't have to be coffee. It's actually the properties of the material composing the mug itself that you're checking. Microwave ovens heat by emitting energy in a wavelength that selectively excites water molecules in food. If the mug gets hotter than the contents when you heat it in a microwave oven, that means that there is something in the mug's composition (probably water molecules, perhaps in tiny cracks in the glazing that are invisible) that is interacting with the microwaves, and counter-indicating its use in the microwave.

Comment: Coffee mugs need washed?

Comment: @BryanJ [shakes 8-ball] Signs point to yes.

Comment: If you heat it long enough it might fix the lack on indentation :D

Comment: Is this where everyone comes to post a photo of their Stack Overflow mug?

Comment: @deW1 Hopefully.

Comment: Thanks for asking this. I hadn't even thought about that yet.

Comment: @doppelgreener Where did you buy this, I'd like to get one.

Comment: @LogicalBranch This was a give-away from [the 2018 stuff-a-way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/321399). As far as I know they aren't for sale.

Answer (score 79):

I've done some science based on Jean-François and Cody's suggestions to try heating up a mug of water in the microwave to test whether it's microwave safe.

The experiment was a huge success:

[image: a microwave erupting in flames]

No, wait, wrong photo. Here:

[image: a nice safe intact mug and a thumbs up]

One mug of warm water in a fairly cool mug. Success! It's microwave safe.

Comment: (**ick!**) It has Java all over it! And I **HATE** the way that code is indented!! (**ick!**)  (Programmers don't need no religion. We can go to war over how braces are indented, or not, in code. You know - over **important** stuff... :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis The java is meant to be on the inside of the mug, whoops.

Comment: we need more Q&As like this from time to time.

Comment: Now to more pressing matters. How was the banana?

Comment: There's no java on the outside (single quotes for the string). JavaScript is on more devices these days.

Comment: @remy_rm [Why did my banana catch fire in the microwave?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/7740/why-did-my-banana-catch-fire-in-the-microwave) may be relevant.

Comment: The code should actually be: `if (owner.isCoding() && mug.isEmpty() && owner.isSipping()) { throw Java.NullPointerException; }`.

Comment: @DavidSherret - frankly, what I find problematic is not so much the Java (or JavaScript), but that the choice of language is literally baked into the mug. One would expect that SO swag would be user-configurable, at least in terms of language, color, capacity, diameter, height, handle/no handle (`hMug`, anyone?), material, and other mug-gy attributes I haven't even thought of yet. Is this some sort of beta version mug that got shipped by accident? :-)

Comment: @BobJarvis If it compiles, ship it.

Comment: That's one heck of a NullPointerException in that first picture. Apparently Java is flammable

Comment: @Lundin - but if it's interpreted..?

Comment: @BobJarvis Then don't ship it.

Comment: You actually can [do this at home](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCrtk-pyP0I).

Comment: But it isn't Java, though.  Strings are double-quoted.  Java*Script*, sure.

Answer (score 55):

If by "dishwasher safe" you mean "they will never, ever fade away"...then no.  The logo and text will eventually fade off after so many wash cycles.  It has to be a lot though; I've had my mug for at least three years now and the text is definitely showing signs of fading, but it's still *somewhat* legible.

See?  "Somewhat".

[image]
[image]

Otherwise, if you're comfortable with a *little* wear down of the logo and text, then it's fine - the cup itself is pretty durable ceramic, and won't take any actual damage* in a dishwasher.

<sup>*:  Provided that you load your dishwasher racks properly - consult YouTube/Google/WikiHow/your dishwasher's instruction manual for more details.</sup>

Comment: but can I put my diamond in the dishwasher?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre:  You can do whatever you wish with your diamond, just be sure that the insurance policy for it is still valid. :D

Comment: Can you please provide documentation for your answer?

Comment: @CannonMoyer:  If it dawns on me after work, I'll take pictures of the mug I've received from Stack Overflow showcasing its wear and tear.

Comment: Can you also include photographs of a correctly loaded dishwasher? It seems too many people are unaware of the proper way of doing this.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - the diamond will not be damaged by the dishwasher, providing it's a real diamond. If the diamond is damaged by the dishwasher, it was not a real diamond, and therefore a diamond was not damaged by a dishwasher. If a dishwasher is damaged by a diamond, then the dishwasher was not a real dishwasher, and therefore a dishwasher was not damaged by a diamond. So I say pour a bucket of sand into your dishwasher and go for it. Best of luck.

Comment: @BobJarvis What if it's a diamond dishwasher?

Comment: @doppelgreener: diamond dishwashers are only useful for washing diamond dishes. They'll break every other kind of dish put in there. KIDS! THESE PEOPLE ARE PROFESSIONALS!! DON'T TRY THIS AT HOME!!!

Comment: @BobJarvis Q.E.D. Excellent logic.

Comment: @BobJarvis I followed your helpful advice and I put [Diamond Brite](https://www.melaleuca.com/ProductStore/Product?sku=2655) in my diamond dishwasher and then poured a bucket of sand in said diamond dishwasher, as I am a professional I then "went for it". I am happy to report the results: ***diamonds***! What kind of black sorcery is this?

Comment: "Hello? Yes, yes, I just saw it. No...no...well, how was I to know someone would actually..? Yes? Well, certainly, if you think it's necessary, minister. I'll attend to it directly. Thank you, minister".  (****sigh****) **OBLIVIATE!!!!!!!!!** There, that should fix it. Humph. "Black sorcery" indeed...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre If you place it in the dishwasher, your moderator tools will be destroyed as soon as it starts washing as the diamond destroys itself in the dishwasher. It is intended for moderators to moderate content, not dishwashers to wash away PII :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre A diamond is like a fine wine, it must first be aged!